# Set up auto login to Moodle from external site

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

We are having a external site where customer can select their preferred authentication method(SSO, username/password). Customer's can have multiple users on their account and if they already have IDP provider, they can integrate with our external site.

Now we have added Moodle and currently adding users manually. Is there a way where I can add a button/link on the site which takes to moodle and auto login to their account. As new user can be added on the external site, Can we also create new users on moodle in this way or API call?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend installing the SAML2 plugin

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2

New users can be created at login and it can handle multiple IDPs

It's developed and maintained by Catalyst NZ who are a big contributor to Moodle

Comment: Thanks @Russell. I have used another plugin(auth_userkey) which is developed by Catalyst NZ. It fulfilled all the requirements and looked easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question for how we have integrated in case anyone has same issue.

Figured out there is a plugin which allows login based on the single use token. It also helps creating the accounts for the user if it doesn't exist. Plugin Link - https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_userkey